# Copied old list reference being changed by new list object modification in python

Tags: python, object, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm working on this problem: http://codeforces.com/contest/540/problem/C

It seems to be a standard breadth first search on a coordinate plane, so essentially, you can move horizontally or vertically, updating the new position's cell with the character 'X' each time you move

In order to solve it, I have to create a list of all possible adjacent State objects, where a 'State' object holds a position and a 2d array (the coordinate plane/matrix). I create this list of adjacent 'State' objects in my 'getAdjacentStates' class function below:

```
class State(object):

def __init__(self, matrix, curPosition):
    self.curMatrix = matrix
    self.curPosition = curPosition

def __hash__(self):
    hash = 0
    mult = 1
    for row in range(len(self.curMatrix)):
        for col in range(len(self.curMatrix[0])):
            if(self.curMatrix[row][col] == 'X'):
                hash += mult * 1
            mult*=2
    return hash

def __eq__(self, other):
    for i, row in enumerate(other.curMatrix):
        for j, col in enumerate(other.curMatrix[0]):
            if not(self.curMatrix[i][j] == other.curMatrix[i][j]):
                return False
    return True


#adjacentStates
def getAdjacentStates(self):
    #calculate a new matrix from curMatrix based on horizontal and vertical position movements
    #curMatrix & curPosition

    adjStates = list()

    if(self.curPosition.column > 0):
        # Subtract one from the column of the current position
        leftPos = Position(self.curPosition.row, self.curPosition.column - 1)
        adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, leftPos))

    if(self.curPosition.column < len(self.curMatrix[0]) - 1):
        # Add one to the column of the current position
        rightPos = Position(self.curPosition.row, self.curPosition.column + 1)
        adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, rightPos))

    if(self.curPosition.row > 0):
        # Subtract one from the current position's row
        downPos = Position(self.curPosition.row-1, self.curPosition.column)
        adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, downPos))

    if(self.curPosition.row < len(self.curMatrix) - 1):
        # Add one to the row of the current position
        upPos = Position(self.curPosition.row + 1, self.curPosition.column)
        adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, upPos))
    #print()
    return adjStates
```

with an additional function:

```
def createState(stateMatrix, position):
    newMatrix = list()
    newMatrix = [stateMatrix[row] for row in range(len(stateMatrix))]
    newMatrix[position.row][position.column] = 'X'
    return State(newMatrix, position)
```

This all works in terms of navigating in the correct directions, but when I print out the list of adjacent states with the given initial state as:

```
5 4
.X..
...X
X.X.
....
.XX.
5 3
1 1
```

I get 3 of the same:

```
.X..
...X
X.X.
..X.
.XXX

.X..
...X
X.X.
..X.
.XXX

.X..
...X
X.X.
..X.
.XXX
```

even though it should look something like this:

```
.X..
...X
X.X.
....
.XX.

.X..
...X
X.X.
....
.XXX

.X..
...X
X.X.
..X.
.XX.
```

don't mind the flaw in walking onto an 'X'

In comparison of what it should be and what I get, for some reason the adjacent State objects all have pointers to a common 'curMatrix' field. I have no idea why, because in my 'createState' function, I create a totally separate list object and return a new State object.

If anyone could provide some advice on how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate the beginner help with python, thank you!

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
import queue

class Position(object):
    def __init__(self, row, column):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column


def createState(stateMatrix, position):
    newMatrix = list()
    newMatrix = [stateMatrix[row] for row in range(len(stateMatrix))]
    newMatrix[position.row][position.column] = 'X'
    return State(newMatrix, position)

class State(object):

    def __init__(self, matrix, curPosition):
        self.curMatrix = matrix
        self.curPosition = curPosition

    def __hash__(self):
        hash = 0
        mult = 1
        for row in range(len(self.matrix)):
            for col in range(len(self.matrix[0])):
                if(self.matrix[row][col] == 'X'):
                    hash += mult * 1
                mult*=2
        return hash

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for i, row in enumerate(other.curMatrix):
            for j, col in enumerate(other.curMatrix[0]):
                if not(self.curMatrix[i][j] == other.curMatrix[i][j]):
                    return False
        return True


    #adjacentStates
    def getAdjacentStates(self):
        #calculate a new matrix from curMatrix based on horizontal and vertical position movements
        #curMatrix & curPosition
        adjStates = list()
        if(self.curPosition.column > 0):
            # Subtract one from the column of the current position
            leftPos = Position(self.curPosition.row, self.curPosition.column - 1)
            adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, leftPos))
        if(self.curPosition.column < len(self.curMatrix[0]) - 1):
            # Add one to the column of the current position
            rightPos = Position(self.curPosition.row, self.curPosition.column + 1)
            adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, rightPos))

        if(self.curPosition.row > 0):
            # Subtract one from the current position's row
            downPos = Position(self.curPosition.row-1, self.curPosition.column)
            adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, downPos))

        if(self.curPosition.row < len(self.curMatrix) - 1):
            # Add one to the row of the current position
            upPos = Position(self.curPosition.row + 1, self.curPosition.column)
            adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, upPos))
        #print()
        return adjStates



    #isFinalState

    def __repr__(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(self.curMatrix):
            for j, col in enumerate(self.curMatrix[i]):
                print(self.curMatrix[i][j], end='')
            print()



n, m = list(map(int, input().split()))
startMatrix = [list(input()) for x in range(n)] #startMatrix[row][column]
startRow, startColumn = list(map(int, input().split()))
startPos = Position(startRow-1, startColumn-1)
endRow, endColumn = list(map(int, input().split()))
endPos = Position(endRow-1, endColumn-1)

initialState = createState(startMatrix, startPos)

testAdj = initialState.getAdjacentStates()
for adj in testAdj:
    adj.__repr__()
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you use the same lists in `adjStates.append(createState(self.curMatrix, xxxPos))`

```
def createState(stateMatrix, position):
    newMatrix = list()
    newMatrix = [stateMatrix[row] for row in range(len(stateMatrix))]
    newMatrix[position.row][position.column] = 'X'
    return State(newMatrix, position)
```

I suppose you need copies of original lists, so change the above code to:

```
def createState(stateMatrix, position):
    # it is superfluous code, so I've just commented it
    # newMatrix = list()

    # Here is the change - create copies of all source lists
    # newMatrix = [list(stateMatrix[row]) for row in range(len(stateMatrix))]
    # But there is a simpler way - iterate direct through list items:
    newMatrix = [list(row) for row in stateMatrix]
    newMatrix[position.row][position.column] = 'X'
    return State(newMatrix, position)
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea why this worked, because I originally did the same thing, where I didn't call 'newMatrix = list()' first and instead did:
'newMatrix = [stateMatrix[row] for row in range(len(stateMatrix))]'
first, which to me seems the same as your change's first line: 
'newMatrix = [list(row) for row in stateMatrix]'. If you have a moment, can you please elaborate why 'newMatrix = list()' was using the same list object? Also, thank you, thank you, xinfinity

Comment: The key point is how you create a copy of existing list of lists. `stateMatrix = [a, b, c]`, `newMatrix = [a, b, c]`. newMatrix is not stateMatrix. But `newMatrix[0] is stateMatrix[0]`, and it is `a`. To create copies of lists `a, b, c` you should call `list(a), list(b), list(c)`. Simple example: `a = [[1,2], [3,4]]` if you create `b = [row for row in a]` then `a[0]` and `b[0]` are the same object, so when you change items of b[0] you also change items of a[0]. If you create `b = [list(row) for row in a]`, then b[0] and a[0] are different objects, so changes on b[0] do not affect a[0].

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. That makes sense. I wasn't thinking in terms of the variables being pointers, and not using list() to construct a totally separate object. Thanks for the help and the extra lesson! :D